# Iterate JSON from CSV

Tags: python, json, loops, csv, variables

I need to create a loop for an API that pulls data from a CSV. The loop should add a comma at the end of {
"id": BRANCH_ID1,
"with_descendants": True
}

and then repeat the same 4 lines for every row under BRANCH_ID1, BRANCH_ID2, where there is a value and then proceed to the close bracket after the last iteration is finished. The USER_ID field will only be used once in the URL for each API Call.

```
import http.client
import json
import csv

with open('sample.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # this is to skip the first line in the csv file
    for USER_ID, BRANCH_ID in reader:
     conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.api.com")
     payload = json.dumps({
          "node_list": [
           {
              "id": BRANCH_ID1,
              "with_descendants": True
           },
           {
              "id": BRANCH_ID2,
              "with_descendants": True
           },
           {
              "id": BRANCH_ID3,
              "with_descendants": True
           }
          ]
        })
    
    conn.request("PUT", f"/poweruser/v1/powerusers/USER_ID/branches?access_token=0ae4f75d988900902dd9bfaa2df048e80a6fb30b", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Sample.csv:

```
USER_ID,BRANCH_ID1,BRANCH_ID2,BRANCH_ID3,BRANCH_ID4,BRANCH_ID5, can keep going on as necessary
14411,332,441,446,445,110
15512,445,221,224
24412,567
23211,955,224
```

Comment: And what is wrong with what you have posted?

Comment: It doesn't actually iterate through each column

Answer (score 0):

This will create your payloads.  You can add back the HTTP manipulations.  There's no point in using the `csv` module; what you have is not a legitimate CSV file because you have a variable number of fields.

```
import json

for row in open('sample.csv'):
    parts = row.strip().split(',')
    if parts[0] == 'USER_ID':
        header = parts
    else:
        nodes = [{"id": int(i), "with_descendents": True} for i in parts[1:]]
        payload = json.dumps( {"node_list": nodes} )
        print(payload)
```

Output:

```
{"node_list": [{"id": 332, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 441, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 446, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": "445", "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 110, "with_descendents": true}]}
{"node_list": [{"id": 445, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 221, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 224, "with_descendents": true}]}
{"node_list": [{"id": 567, "with_descendents": true}]}
{"node_list": [{"id": 955, "with_descendents": true}, {"id": 224, "with_descendents": true}]}
```

Comment: how do I pull the User ID for the HTTP 
conn.request("PUT", f"/poweruser/v1/powerusers/{USER_ID}/branches?access_token=675e914048bd784a6f38b175501f4c5783e17bbb", payload)

Comment: This won't work because it's outputting the ID in quotes

Comment: Surely you know how to convert a string to an integer.  Your code above wasn't doing that, either.